# This is postfix calculator program and I'm getting an unrecognized operand error

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, postfix-notation

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BS {

public static void main (String [] args){
    LinkedStack s = new LinkedStack();
    String a = " 1 6 /";
    Scanner t = new Scanner(a);
    int result = 0;

    while(t.hasNext()){
        if(t.hasNextInt()){
            s.push(t.nextInt());                
        }           
        else
        {               
            String operator = t.next();         
            System.out.println(operator);

            int op1, op2;

            if(s.isEmpty())
                throw new RuntimeException ("not enough operants");


            op2 = s.pop();

            if(s.isEmpty())
                throw new RuntimeException ("not enough operator");

            op1 = s.pop();          

            if(operator.equals('+'))
                result = op2 + op1;
            if(operator.equals('-'))
                result = op2-op1;
            if(operator.equals('*'))
                result = op2*op1;
            if(operator.equals('/'))
                result = op2/op1;               
            else 
                throw new RuntimeException ("unrecognize operands");
        }           
    }

    System.out.println(result);     
    }
}
```

This is postfix calculator program. but for some reason I'm getting the unrecognized operand error.
The program is not recognizing the '/' sign. I don't know why?

Comment: Your original question has been answered. You need to ask the modified question separately and what's more important you need to provide the `input` string that you are invoking it with.

Comment: I have submitted my new question separately under "PostFix Calculator debugging" if you could please look it is and help me I would appreciated.

Comment: Here is the link to the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21494797/postfix-calculator-debugging

Answer (score 0):

The `if` block is wrong. The `else` is only applying to the last `if`. It should be

```
        if(operator.equals('+'))
            result = op2 + op1;
        else if(operator.equals('-'))
            result = op2-op1;
        else if(operator.equals('*'))
            result = op2*op1;
        else if(operator.equals('/'))
            result = op2/op1;
        else 
            throw new RuntimeException ("unrecognize operands");
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked about recognising the '/' sign. Apart from fixing your `if` block as suggested by @Johnny Mopp, the main problem is that you should be comparing to strings read from `java.util.Scanner` and not to characters. Change this, and all the other operands to compare strings:

```
if(operator.equals("/"))
    result = op2/op1;
```

Here's your code working and printing `6`: http://ideone.com/HVAqQX

Comment: That worked for the this program thanks but why doesnt it it work when using this next program is is basically the same?